# Adding redundant information to database to simplify query model

Tags: database-design, language-agnostic, query-optimization

Lets imagine I have something resembling the following contrived example

```
ParkingSpace         Car                   ParkingSpaceCar
-------------        -------------         ---------------
Id                   Id                    ParkingSpaceId
                     Date                  CarId
```

So I have a history of all cars which have ever been allocated to any specific parking space, which is great.

But in order to find the currently allocated car, I have to do a query matching on the most recent `Date` in `Car`, which is adding an overhead in terms of LOC and performance.

So my question is, is it acceptable to add an `IsCurrent` field on `ParkingSpaceCar` to simplify data extraction, even though it's effectively a redundant field (as it can be infered from the data already present).

NB: I'm interested in the answer in general terms, I'm aware that the specific above example is a bit silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a heavily normalized model is great, as usually that gives the designer a lot of knowledge about the domain data model.

However, once you start writing queries the cracks start showing. It's true that a normalized database will be able to answer every query, and use less space to store the data, but at the price of join after join *(e.g. a tax rate of the invoice is taken from the `Taxes` table via the `TaxesByCounty` table via the `Counties` table via the `Cities` table)*, and aggregate function after aggregate function *(eg. the total value of an invoice is constantly calculated from the order items, instead of being stored in the `Invoices` table)*.

So, once the real data pours in the database, and some real queries are writen, it's [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) time. Denormalization esentially duplicates data where it's needed, and can sometimes incur some maintenance dificulties, but is well worth the effort. What data should be duplicated should be pointed out by some performance metrics, but usually there are some obvious candidates.

Comment: A normalized database will not necessarily use less space though. Normalization has nothing to with storage size. Your examples of when to denormalize also raise more questions than answers. Wouldn't tax rate depend on the invoice date? It seems very possible that having the tax rate on the invoice would be in at least BCNF anyway. You'll still need those joins in order to determine what the tax rate should be when the invoice is created.

Comment: @Dportas: 1. Yes, it's not guaranteed that a normalized db will use less space than a non-normalized, but that's often the naive argument used for `why we need normalization`. My point is that storage space is almost irrelevant in this day and age, and that database performance, clarity and maintainabillity should be the driving motivators behind the design process.

Comment: @dportas: the examples are just that - off-the-top-of-my-head examples that overly normalized databases can be (and usually are) tedious to work with. And yes, we'll need to join and calculate on insert or update (slowing those operations), but we'll speed up selects by a factor. If the gathered performance petrics show that we have an insert once every 1000 selects, it's a valid trade off.

Comment: @Sweko, Performance and maintainability should not be the driving motivations behind database design. Data integrity should come first. Normalization is about integrity, not performance and storage. The trouble is your top-of-the-head example isn't really an example of "over-normalization" at all - recording the tax code on an invoice isn't an example of denormalization. With an example like that you are in danger of promoting misconceptions about what is or isn't denormalized.

Comment: Excessive numbers of joins are often the price of excessive numbers of id numbers. I find it helpful to analyze how often critical information is contained in a natural candidate key. (It happens a lot more often that I thought.) In the OP's case, creating a carefully indexed view and tuning the server might be the best use of time.

Comment: @dportas: That's like saying that lower fuel consumption is not a driving motivation behind vehicle design, whether the car can be driven is. IMHO, A database without data integrity is a clump of data, not a database. I **need** my data to be clean, but I **want** my db to be fast and easily maintained. And the example is purely hypotetical to illustrate a point, please provide a better one, and I'll edit the response.

Comment: SWeko, Glad you agree on integrity, performance, maintainability. Denormalization compromises on all three because it entails creating and maintaining redundant data. It means you'll need additional logic to update data and maintain integrity in multiple places and it creates the potential for the data to be inconsistent or at least ambiguous. Denormalization should be avoided for those reasons. I don't think another example would be necessary or helpful.

Comment: @dportas: Agreed with that, but I wouldn't say that one should never use denormalization. If one has solid performance data, and good working knowledge of the domain, a little (controlled) redundancy can go a long way. Take OLAP, for example, it's all redundancy and precomputation there.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to design the database I would do it like this

```
ParkingSpace         Car                   ParkingSpaceCar
-------------        -------------         ---------------
Id                   Id                    ParkingSpaceId
                                           CarId
                                           ParkDate
```

So everytime I query I will just use the park date and that includes every details(CarID and ParkSpaceID)

I could just sort everything by ParkDate.

Answer (score 1):

The model doesn't make much sense to me. It seems like the date belongs in the ParkingSpaceCar table anyway. The answer therefore is no. Make sure your database is in Normal Form to start with and the problem will probably go away. Avoid introducing bias into the design to support one particular type of operation on the data because this will usually only make other operations more complex.

Comment: Of course it doesn't make sense. I just made it up. It's clearly ridiculous. But that wasn't my question.

Comment: I answered your question: normalise your database. I can't tell you what is or isn't normalised without a proper example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is sometimes appropriate to do things like this.

The general term for this is [denormalizaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization): You actively break some [rules of normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) in order to get some advantage (usually query performance).

Since normalization has a lot of advantages you should think carefully if the improved performance outweighs the drawbacks (such as the possibility of inconsistent data).

Answer (score 0):

I'd broadly go for a star schema / data warehouse approach.

- DimDate (one row per date, primary key kDate)
- DimCar (one row per car, primary key kCar)
- DimParkingSpace (one row per parking space, primary key kParkingSpace)

Then create a Fact table

- FactParkingAllocation (one row per car and date and parkingspace, foreign keys kDate, kCar, kParkingSpace)

I wouldn't bother with a flag on the FactParkingAllocation table showing current, as this will need to be updated frequently, instead, I would have a view on the table which subset on the basis of 'todays' date (I'll leave the SQL logic to you as that depends on your DBMS).